# How to proceed with dimensionless recasting of telegrapher's equation?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, diffusion, normalization

I am referring to [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08474.pdf) paper, on page 3 it is given that:

> The telegrapher's equation is given as
>   $$\partial_t P_+=D\partial_x^2P_+-v\partial_xP_+-\gamma P_++\gamma P_-,$$
>   $$\partial_t P_-=D\partial_x^2P_-+v\partial_xP_-+\gamma P_+-\gamma P_-.$$
>   where $P_+(x; t)$ and $P_-(x; t)$ are the probability density for the particle to be at position x with velocities $+v$ and $-v$, respectively. Furthermore, choosing
>   $\gamma^-1$ as the unit of time and $v\gamma^-1$ as the unit of length to
>   recast the above given equations in the dimensionless form, we get
>   $$\partial_t P_+=\mathcal{D}\partial_x^2P_+-\partial_xP_+- P_++P_-,$$
>   $$\partial_t P_-=\mathcal{D}\partial_x^2P_-+\partial_xP_-+ P_+- P_-$$
>   where $\mathcal{D}=D\gamma/v^2$.

This transition is not a simple subsitution, I want to know how they they have proceeded with **recasting equations to dimensionless form**. I tried to check in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondimensionalization), but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to answer the question using help from wikipedia link:
taking $P_+=aP_+$,$P_-=bP_-$, $t=t_c\tau$, $x=x_c\zeta$, where $\tau , \zeta$ are the new independent variables. We can solve the given equation, for dimensionality take $\gamma/v=1/x_c$, $b/a=1$ and $t_c\gamma=1$ all these are dimensionally compatible leading to the given normalization. :)